# Why does executing 'grub-install/dev/nvme0m1' failed shows after following all steps to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on new HP spectre 360?

Tags: grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I want to install Ubuntu 19.1 alongside Windows 10. My laptop is: HP - Spectre x360 2-in-1 13.3" 4K OLED Ultra HD Touch-Screen Laptop - Intel Core i7 - 16GB Memory - 1TB SSD + 32GB Optane.

To do that I followed the step:

1) Create a free space using 'shrink volume' in Disk Management of Windows 10. I set this side to 500 GB. Here it shows the 500 GB of unallocated space.

2) I turn off windows 10 quick start in the advanced power options.

3) I download Ubuntu 19.1 from the ubuntu website.

4) I create a boot flash drive with the ubuntu 19.10 using Rufus. My drive is GPT, thus I select GPT as partition scheme and UEFI as the target system.

5) I disable 'Secure boot' in the BIOS

6) I select the UEFI flash drive as main booting option.

7) I save changes and the PC restarts from the flash drive and I select 'install Ubuntu'.

8) I select normal installation, install updates, and third party drives. Then hit continue.

9) I select 'something else'.

10) I choose the 500 GB of free space that I created previously. Hit '+' to create a: 500 MB of UEFI partition; 32 GB of 'swap'; 20 GB of '\' with ext4 journaling file system; and, the remaining I use for '\home' with ext4 journaling file system as well. I choose primary for all of them.

11) In 'Device for boot installation' I choose '/dev/nvme0n1'. Then I hit 'install now'

Installation goes well until it reaches something saying grub2 and then get this error that says: Executing 'grub-install/dev/nvme0n1' failed.

This is the first time I am trying to install Ubuntu. I have read and followed all the information but it does not work. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: There was no Ubuntu release in 2019-January (19.1); so do you mean 19.10?  (*the 2019-October release or 19.04 the 2019-April release*).

Comment: sorry. I meant 19.10
I edited the question to 19.10 already